# Jasper date_sub error

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have a query in Jasper:

```
     SELECT
         date_format(
         DATE_SUB(a.start_stamp, INTERVAL 5 hour),
         "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"
         ) as date,
    FROM
    a
```

which runs fine if I run it separately from Jasper, but in Jasper gives an error. If I hover over the hour word it says: extraneous input hour, expecting ')'. Also if I remove the DATE_SUB it gives no error.
How can I fix this?(I am using Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Does Jasper accept this?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.start_stamp-INTERVAL 5 HOUR,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `date`
  FROM a
```

The query in your question has a extra comma after `as date`. It also gives `date` as a column name in a resultset, notwithstanding the fact that DATE is a reserved SQL word. It also uses double quotes to surround the format string, even thought single quotes are usually used for this purpose in MySQL.

I have also changed the date arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   date_format(
     DATE_SUB(a.start_stamp, INTERVAL 5 hour),
     "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"
  ) as date
FROM 
   a
```

Date_Format return the value in string so that is the reason it is giving an error.
Solution
Remove date_Format from Query and use text field Date Format option.

Try with below 1 so you can test it.

```
 SELECT date_format(
        DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 hour),
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"
) as date
```